# R Split data.frame columns into rows (unequal vector lenghts)

Tags: r, split

He

I am currently having the following data frame

```
+-----+-------+...more than 2k wide
|  V1 |  V2   |
+-----+-------+...
|  1,2| a,b,c |
|  2  | a,c   |
|  3  | b,d   |
|  4  | e,f   |
|  .. | ...   |
+-----+-------+
```

And I now want to split all of the comma separated columns keeping everything in one huge data frame. The problem is that the length of
the vectors is differing in the rows. If that would not be the case 
a simple

```
df %>% separate_rows(V1:V2, sep = ",")
```

Would do the job. I am now facing doing each of the columns separately and then put them together. However that will take ages
for all of the more than 2k columns. So any help with this would
be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `library(splitstackshape)`

Comment: Thanks. It works!